# IIS Rewriting url with parameter

Tags: url-rewriting

I'm trying to setup rewrite for url from `/place/search-the-places/item-detail/id=123` to `/place/explore-our-places/item-detail/id=123`

but it doesn't work, what I'm doing wrong?

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Collections" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^place/search-the-places/item-detail/id=([0-9]+)" ignoreCase="true" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="/place/explore-our-places/item-detail/?id={R:1}" />
                <conditions>
                </conditions>
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to match numeric id as a parameter, then instead of

```
id=([0-9]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)
```

use

```
id=([0-9]+)
```

because the slash between regexes means your route is like this

```
/place/search-the-places/item-detail/id=123/end-of-route
```

and this is not true, I suppose.

Also try using `type="Rewrite"` instead of `"Redirect"`.

Comment: Also try using type="Rewrite" instead of "Redirect"

Comment: Still no luck with it?